# Multiple <meta> Tags with the Same Name

Tags: html, meta-tags

I need to specify multiple copyrights or authors using the `<meta>` tag. Can I use a `<meta>` tag with the same name multiple times?

```
<meta name="copyright" content="Company A" />
<meta name="copyright" content="Company B" />
```

Will the search engine respect both values? Or, do I need to comma-separate them in one `<meta>` tag?

Thanks.

Comment: As the answers confirm, OP did not ask for a personal opinion, but information about how these alternatives will technically interact with other tools like search engines. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @joanis I see "What would be the best way...?" and "Or is it better...?" which appear to ask for opinions. If you think those questions are not germaine, you should [edit] the question to remove them.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sure, I'll bite. I just reworded the question to keep the germane issue and remove the unnecessary wording that suggests it's an opinion question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using multiple meta tags with the same name is valid HTML.

But we don't know how search engines and other readers will interpret them. Either two meta tags will be concatenated or one of them will be ignored/overwritten.

Example: The PHP-function [`get_meta_tags()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) will only return the value of the last meta tag if multiple meta tags have an equal name.

To avoid possible problems I would recommend to use a single meta tag:

```
<meta name="copyright" content="Company A, Company B" />
```

Comment: Another example is when developing for tizen devices. Then only the last meta-tag is used. All others are ignored.

Answer (score 7):

If the page contains multiple meta tags of the same type, Google will aggregate the content values. For instance, they will interpret

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX">
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOFOLLOW">
```

The same way as:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

More details here:http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ro/2007/03/using-robots-meta-tag.html

I guess most other search engines would handle the meta tags in the same way.

Comment: There's very specifically about `robots`. You shouldn't assume the behaviour is a general case.