# Why are there three meta content tags with the same values for this web article?

Tags: html, reactjs, meta

Why are there three meta content tags with the same values for this web article.

I'm wondering if it is a mistake or if it serves a functional purpose?

If so what purpose does it serve?

https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/lemon-juice-acidic-or-alkaline

```
<meta content="Despite its acidic pH, some people say lemon 
juice has alkalizing effects in the body. 
This article takes a look at the science behind this claim." 
name="description" class="next-head" data-reactroot=""/>
```

This question is different from this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531761/multiple-meta-tags-with-the-same-name) in which the values are different.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an SEO question outside [the scope defined by the SEO tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info). It might be on-topic for [the webmasters stackexchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The *question* is SEO related. Xion's answer doesn't make sense.