# Media queries work in inspector but not on phone

Tags: reactjs, deployment, sass, media-queries

I have a basic front end app(REACT/SASS) that utilizes an API to display country data. Media queries work on local and deployed when using chrome inspector, but when i try to view it on my phone, none of the media queries are working, what would cause this?

Below is the index.html head

```
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Below is an example of relevant scss

```
.country-info-ctr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%
}

.info-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  // justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.info-ctr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 40px;

}

.country-info-flag {
  height: 500px !important;
  width: 750px !important;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.country-info-name {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.data-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: space-around;

}

.data-ctr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;

}

.border-button {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(218, 218, 218);
  margin: 9px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.border {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.border-ctr {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.home-bttn {
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 30px 30px 0 30px;
  font-size: 20px;

}

@media (max-device-width: 400px) {

  .country-info-flag {
    height: 240px !important;
    width: 320px !important;
  }

  .info-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .info-ctr {
    margin: 20px;
  }

  .data-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .border-ctr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    object-fit: contain;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
  }

  .border-button a {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 1px;

  }

  .border {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there's 2 possible differences between the chrome simulator and an actual device.

First, the mobile device may be ignoring the duplicate `viewport` meta tags. Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531761/multiple-meta-tags-with-the-same-name), while having the same `name` attribute on multiple `meta` tags is valid HTML, some browser/parsers may not handle them properly. In this case, it's possible that on your mobile device, only the second `viewport` tag is being used, so `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` is being ignored completely.

You could try combining everything into one `meta` tag like so:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`

The second potential difference between the chrome simulator and the browser on an actual device is that `max-device-width` media queries may not be supported. Per the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width) they're deprecated. You should try use `@media (max-width: 400px)`

Comment: i changed the meta tag to reflect the above changes and the media query is still not working. could it be something with the way the media query is written?

Comment: Yup, turns out `max-device-width` is deprecated. I updated my answer with a potential fix for that.